# I have two schengen visas

Tags: visas, schengen

I have two Schengen visas. One is from the Netherlands and expires on 27-8-2015. My other visa is from France and starts on 28-8-2015.

My travel date is on 19-8-2015 so I will enter through Amsterdam airport and then I will travel to Ibiza on 21-8-2015.

I want to go back to Amsterdam on 6-9-2015. Can I travel home from Amsterdam or do I have to go to Paris to travel home?

Comment: Since it appears the largest part of your trip will be in Spain, then Spain probably should have issued the second visa. But you should be OK if you don't exceed the 90/180 day rule...and you go to Paris at some point.